# How to use Regex pattern with variable

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to replace "=channel" with a string variable because this string changes all the time.
Pattern1 returns '-4jsdioiuu--678' as expected but pattern2 never returns a match.
I can't figure out why.

```
string source_to_parse = "testtet=channel-4jsdioiuu--678=kl";
string pattern_var = "=channel";
string pattern1 = @"=channel[\w\-]*"; // working
string pattern2 = @"pattern_var + [\w\-]*"; // not working
var parse_result = Regex.Match(source_to_parse, pattern2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[0].Value;
```

Comment: Is it literally declared as `@"pattern_var + [\w\-]*"`? If so, it should be incredibly obvious why it isn't working.. It's not using the `pattern_var` variable (i.e. `"=channel"`)

Comment: Should be `string pattern2 = pattern_var + @"[\w\-]*";` Right now, you are passing the literal string `pattern_var + ...` instead of concatenating your `pattern_var` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use an existing string variable within a second one, you can either concatenate them:

```
 string pattern2 = pattern_var + @"[\w\-]*";
```

Or you can use string interpolation (or something like `string.Format`, but why use more code when few code do trick?):

```
string pattern2 = $@"{pattern_var}[\w\-]*";
```

What you currently have is looking for the literal value `pattern_var`, which obviously isn't what you're after.